# Unable to parse Feature file in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin, web-api-testing, feature-file

```
I am unable to parse my feature file in cucumber while running i am getting following error, i am creating a BDD test framework to do API testing using cumber feature file concept
```

io.cucumber.core.gherkin.FeatureParserException: Failed to parse resource at: file:///D:/NodeApiTesting/APITestingNode/src/test/resources/functionalTests/End2End_Test.feature
at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.GherkinVintageFeatureParser.parseGherkin5(GherkinVintageFeatureParser.java:40)
at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.GherkinVintageFeatureParser.parse(GherkinVintageFeatureParser.java:58)
at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureParser.parseResource(FeatureParser.java:44)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.lambda$new$0(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:39)
at java.util.function.BiFunction.lambda$andThen$0(Unknown Source)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.lambda$processResource$2(ResourceScanner.java:126)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:67)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:52)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForPath(PathScanner.java:46)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForUri(PathScanner.java:26)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.findResourcesForUri(ResourceScanner.java:109)
at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.scanForResourcesUri(ResourceScanner.java:86)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.loadFeatures(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:62)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.get(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:46)
at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.(Cucumber.java:156)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.internal.gherkin.ParserException$CompositeParserException: Parser errors:
(1:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Scenario Outline: User generates token for Authorisation'
(2:2): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Given I am an authorized user'
(4:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Scenario Outline: the Authorized user can Add and Remove a phone'
(5:2): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Given A list of phones are available'
(6:2): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'When I add a phone to store'
(7:2): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Then the phone is added'
(8:2): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'When I update a phone in my store'
(9:2): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Then the phone is updated'
(10:2): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'When I remove a phone from my store'
(11:2): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Then the book is removed'
(12:2): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'When I am reading my phone details'
at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.internal.gherkin.Parser.addError(Parser.java:152)
at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.internal.gherkin.Parser.matchTokenAt_0(Parser.java:491)
at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.internal.gherkin.Parser.matchToken(Parser.java:337)
at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.internal.gherkin.Parser.parse(Parser.java:137)
at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.internal.gherkin.Parser.parse(Parser.java:118)
at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.internal.gherkin.Parser.parse(Parser.java:114)
at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.GherkinVintageFeatureParser.parseGherkin5(GherkinVintageFeatureParser.java:29)
... 34 more

my feature file is as follows

**End2End_Test.feature**

```
Scenario Outline: User generates token for Authorisation
    Given I am an authorized user

Scenario Outline: the Authorized user can Add and Remove a phone
    Given A list of phones are available
    When I add a phone to store
    Then the phone is added
    When I update a phone in my store
    Then the phone is updated
    When I remove a phone from my store
    Then the book is removed
    When I am reading my phone details
    Then I read my Phone Details
```

My runner.java file is as follows

**TestRunner.java**

```
package runners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/functionalTests",
        glue = {"stepDefinitions"},
        monochrome = true,
        strict = true
)
public class TestRunner {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Scenario Outline` you need `Examples`.

If you don't need example just use `Scenario`

```
Feature: My feature name
  As a customer
  I should be able to do something
  So that I can benefit

 Scenario: Some test - some test description
  Given i have something
  When i do some action
  Then the results are displayed


 Scenario Outline: Some other test - scenario outline needs examples
  Given i have something
  When i do some action with <example_name>
  Then the results are displayed
Examples:
  | example_name |
  | test         |
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes extent report plugin which we add in runner file CucumberOption "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:" give the same parser exception.

Comment: error: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/internal/gherkin/ParserException

Comment: if you are using extentreports-cucumber6-adapter then version must be 2.8.2